# Music is to ____?____ as chemistry is to IUPAC

Tags: theory, notation

I was wondering if there is any governing body for music theory like IUPAC is for chemistry.

Comment: It might help the non-chemists to briefly explain what IUPAC is.

Comment: Chemistry is about facts.  Music is about creating.  What is it that you would 'govern' ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It might be useful to standardize terminology, for example.

Comment: It's only useful to "standardize terminology" if it is used to communicate something important and there are significant consequences if the communication fails. That is clearly important in chemistry, but completely unimportant for music - unless somebody can provide solid evidence that using incorrect music terminology might kill people!

Comment: OP is asking about is there any institutes/convention that provide the 'standard' values. IUPAC is international Union for Pure and Applied Chemistry; or similarly many physics standards stored at Bureau of Weights and Measures.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for an organization and unrelated to performance of music.

Comment: Where else would I ask this question...

Answer (score 4):

Internationally, the closest I can think of would be the [Society for Music Theory](https://societymusictheory.org/). The society holds annual conferences, releases a biannual publication called *Music Theory Spectrum*, etc.

Some countries have their own, more specific societies. The [Society for Music Analysis](http://www.sma.ac.uk/) in the UK is especially terrific.

Comment: The SMA may well be a terrific organization, but I would guess that at least 99.99% of active musicians in the UK have never heard of it, and even fewer are actually members.

Comment: I'm not sure that's really relevant. As one reason of several I could list: think about the number of people that are musicians as "just a hobby"; now think about the number of "hobby" chemists!